# mysql functions in query builder in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use the function in MySQL like `convert(name use gbk)`.

How can I use this with Laravel's query builder `with`?

I tried `->orderBy(convert(name using gbk))` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 20):

You need to use the Raw function of eloquent.

```
DB::raw(your sql)
```

In your case, the following query should work:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('convert(name using gbk)'))
```

If you want to use raw sql in your where statements, your can use the shortcut function `whereRaw()` and for a select the `selectRaw()` function.

Comment: By the way, it can be also used as: `->where('t','<=',DB::raw('now()'));`

Comment: I have just used this answer with `COALESCE(`parent_aid`, `aid`), `parent_aid` IS NOT NULL` by just placing `DB::raw()` in `orderBy()`. It works perfect!

Comment: It works with insert as well:   $id = DB::table('mytable')->insertGetId(array('uuid' => DB::raw('uuid()'));