# Cannot use mysql function IN in laravel db statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im having a problem when using the IN function of MySQL in a Laravel 5.2 DB Statement. Here is the example:

```
$str_array = implode(",",$array_reservations);
$sql_result = DB::select("
            select r.id,r.people,r.date,r.status,p.alias,u.name,p.profile
            from  reservations r inner join places p on p.id = r.place_id 
            inner join  users u on u.id = r.user_id
            where r.id in(?)
            order by r.date desc
            ", [$str_array]);
```

But in the result I just get the result of the first reservation of the array.

The length of the array will be always variable.

Comment: Have you tried `DB::raw($query);` ??

Comment: Like @P.Gearman pointed out; refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465243/mysql-functions-in-query-builder-in-laravel

Comment: You can't use a single binding placeholder for an entire IN list, you have to use individual placeholders for each element, and pass `$array_reservations`  as an array, not as a comma-separated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  $sql_result = DB::table('reservations AS r')
        ->join('places AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'r.place_id')
        ->join('users AS u', 'u.id', '=', 'r.user_id')
        ->select('r.id','r.people','r.date','r.status','p.alias','u.name','p.profile')
        ->whereIn('r.id',$str_array)                    // write you conditions in array
        ->orderBy('r.date', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to use DB::raw. Also, you need to create as many "?" you need, for each id you want to bind. That's the way PDO works:

```
$str_array = implode(",",$array_reservations);
$bindings = trim(str_repeat('?,', count($array_reservations)), ',');

DB::select($sql, $inputids);
$sql_result = DB::select(DB::raw("
        select r.id,r.people,r.date,r.status,p.alias,u.name,p.profile
        from  reservations r inner join places p on p.id = r.place_id 
        inner join  users u on u.id = r.user_id
        where r.id in($bindings)
        order by r.date desc
        "), $str_array);
```

But, IMO, you should use Query Builder:

```
DB::table('reservations')
    ->join('places','places.id','=','reservarions.place_id')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','reservarions.user__id')
    ->whereIn('reservations.id',$str_array)
    ->orderBy('reservations.date', 'DESC');
```